how import in my client
bitcoin-cli -rpcwallet=leg importprunedfunds getrawtransaction gettxoutproof

after that I get only read only, what am I doing wrong?

You should be a bit more specific on what you want to do exactly. One introducing sentence would be great here. Only giving a CLI command might be okay for someone who knows exactly what you mean, but others might also be interested, especially when there's an accepted answer.

The documentation for importprunedfunds says

Imports funds without rescan. Corresponding address or script must previously be included in wallet. Aimed towards pruned wallets. The end-user is responsible to import additional transactions that subsequently spend the imported outputs or rescan after the point in the blockchain the transaction is included

(my emphasis)

Related:

Remove descriptor from a Bitcoin Core wallet
How do I import privkeys if my blockchain is pruned?

